# RCT with repeated measures help

Tags: repeated-measures, control-group

I may be overthinking this and going down too many rabbit holes of possibilities, but can someone please help me figure out the appropriate ("best") method to use for this research project?? It's for a randomized control trial with two groups (treatment and control, 60 in each so 120 total), and repeated measures. Note that we do expect a good deal of attrition, so missing data will need to be considered. The outcomes are both continuous measures. The primary outcome will be measures at baseline and post-treatment. The secondary outcome will be measured at two follow-ups that occur after the post-treatment assessment (though I can probably argue to have this one also measured at baseline and/or post-treatment in addition to the two follow-ups).

For the primary outcome, what is the best way to account for the baseline measure of the outcome? Is it as simple as running an ANOVA with group as the main predictor and the baseline as a covariate? Or should this be done in some kind of mixed model?

For the primary, what are my options if we only have the two follow-up measures of the outcome? And what would be the best method if we also assessed this at baseline and/or the post-treatment assessment?

Right now there are no plans to include any covariates, but I'm wondering if that's the best approach- we could, for example, include any that differ between the two groups at baseline and have a relation to the outcome.

Finally, is there an easy way to conduct a power analysis for this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you confirm that "endpoint" and "outcome" are used interchangeably here? There are some disease types, for instance, that have several statuses. Consider "remission" for multiple sclerosis based on the % of plaque intensity on MRI. In analyses like this, several *endpoints* are derived from the *outcome* of plaque intensity: time to response, duration of response, response at 6 months, response at 12 months etc. It would not be appropriate to analyze data like this using ANOVA or fixed effects because the continuous value is not clinically meaningful.

Comment: The outcomes I'm referring to are both self-reported measures of mental health symptoms, assessed at different time points (baseline, post-treatment, follow-up 1, and follow-up 2). Ideally I think we'd like to get estimates of both mean differences in symptoms at each time point, and differences in change over time. By the way, since last posting I think I've convinced the investigators to include both of these measures at each of the 4 timepoints. So I think we need either mixed-effect model for repeated measures or GEE models. Another possibility could be multiple group growth models??

Comment: Growth models and mixed models can be equivalent.

Comment: For power, keep it simple. Ignore baseline and pick one outcome, that ensures you underestimate power, rather than overestimate power.

Comment: I am voting to close for "needs details and clarity" because I think there's insufficient background on the subject area, the outcomes, and the possible endpoints that can be modeled from a longitudinal design. Others may disagree, but word to the wise: if we smoosh the general problem description into a framework we know and understand, it may not be the correct method for this particular discipline.

Comment: @JeremyMiles In my experience, you *have* to power a study for your primary endpoint.  If you consider the several potentially biasing factors affecting the analysis such as regression to the mean, and informative censoring, I would not at all expect the growth and mixed model to be equivalent (assuming by mixed model you specifically mean repeated measures ANCOVA with random slope).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @AdamO - yes, I should have been more explicit. By pick on outcome, I mean pick your primary endpoint. If you do a growth model you'll have more power, and if you include baseline covariate you should have more power, but you don't know how much more. So by keeping it simple you make your life easier AND ensure your power analysis is conservatie.

Comment: And by mixed I meant mixed effect / multilevel. And I agree the question needs to be clearer.